# Extracting javascript syntax from a xml node using R

Tags: javascript, r, xml-parsing, web-scraping

I hope this is not too cumbersome, but I'm trying to extract a javascript syntax from a XML node, or nodeset using R.

I would like to extract a partial url from the following node:

```
[[76]] <'a href="javascript:;" onclick="self.name='regmain'; window.open('regcssm.asp?Cl=23&amp;Lg=1&amp;Co=1201.00', 'regpopup', 'height=400,width=400,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'); return false;">1201.00<'/a>
```

This page is from the [UN Harmonized System for Products Classification](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/cr/registry/regso.asp?Ci=11&Lg=1), which is actually an .asp page.

However, I managed to parse it and find the necessary nodes.

I can't figure out, neither from the web nor within this forum, if R as some capability to extract this url: (regcssm.asp?Cl=23&Lg=1&Co=1201.00). 
I tried xmlGetAttr (it only gives 'javascript') and xpathSApply gives 1201.00.

Is there a way to do so, or to extract this line as a text string from the xml within R?

WIN 7-64BIT, R 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your parsed html is stored in `bar`

```
# Extract the relevant "onclick" attributes
 w <- xpathSApply(bar,path = '//a[@href="javascript:;"][@onclick]',
        fun = xmlGetAttr, "onclick")

# extract the text between brackets `window.open()`  split by `,` and then
# extract the first component and remove `'` 

gsub("'",'',sapply(strsplit(gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", w),','),head,1))
```

Comment: Works as well, so I was missing the extra baracketes with the  `@onclick` attribute. I might stick with it after all, since I alreay familiar with the xml package...

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a shorter answer (i have R version 3.1.1):

```
install.packages("rvest"); install.packages("magrittr")
library(rvest);library(magrittr)
UN <- html("http://unstats.un.org/unsd/cr/registry/regso.asp?Ci=11&Lg=1")
UN %<>% html_nodes(".content table") %>% .[[2]] %>% 
html_nodes(".tcont, .lcont") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% .[-1]
UN %<>% lapply(function(x) x %>% as("character"))
UN %<>% substr(67, 108)
UN
```

Comment: Thanks @dimitris_ps, that was perfect. Didn't know about rvest and magrittr, so I will dive into those as soon as I have some spare time, or at the next time I'll have to perform a similar task.